# Working with layouts in Angular2 app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components, angular2-modules

I have developed an Angular2 app using routing.

My problem scenario is:

I have a Login page which has different HTML and CSS.Once successfully logged in, I redirect to another page which has different HTML and CSS.
But I have index.html(login page) as my main layout. Hence I need to understand how to work with multiple layouts?

I have done some R&D but I am not able to understand how to implement it?

Please find below code:

1) app.routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
{
    path: 'employee',
    component: EmployeeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}];
export class AppRoutingModule {   }
export const routedComponents = [LoginComponent,EmployeeComponent];
```

2) App component

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
           selector: 'my-app',
           template: `
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          `
          })
export class AppComponent {
        constructor() {
        }
}
```

3) App module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule, routedComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';


 @NgModule({
     imports: [BrowserModule,
               HttpModule,
               AppRoutingModule
      ],
     declarations: [AppComponent,
                    routedComponents
     ],
     providers: [AuthGuard],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]

    })
 export class AppModule { }
```

4) Index.html

```
 <my-app>

 </my-app>
```

Any help would be highly appreciable!

Thanks!!

Comment: create `login-page` route component separately, don't use index.html for showing login page, and when someone comes to your app navigate them to login-page route if user is not login. write this logic in your root app component

Comment: post some code here how you are doing. It will be helpful to suggest any solution.

Comment: @satendra please check the code snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove all CSS from index.html and create separate component for login and another component say home for other features.
- Load CSS for login and home in login component and home component respectively.
- Create separate routes for login and home,place all other features routes inside home route as child route.
  Please find below code:

  ```
  {
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
         {
          path: 'childPage',
          component: childPageComponent
         }]
  }
  ```
- Use below line to navigate to child page:

  ```
  this.router.navigate(['/home/childPage'])
  ```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [angular2 component styles](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html)

As said in this reference:

> We have several ways to add styles to a component:
>
> - inline in the template HTML
> - by setting styles
> - or styleUrls metadata with CSS imports

In addition I recommend you create components (and routings) like tree (Hierarchy) in one module. For checking user login status You need one shared service (for example authservice).